# Access dependencies in Gradle build script from project

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have the Gradle build script

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

How can i access over the [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) Object all dependencies which are declared in the build script?
In the [gradle API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) I read that I could use

```
Project.getDependencies()
```

but i not really understand how to access over that all dependencies, I can only add some.
I'm really new with Gradle. Hope someone can help.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the dependencies. There are a number of hooks that Gradle provides to deal with dependencies, what's your goal?

Comment: @romtsn I want write in my build script something like this:
`if(project.dependencies.contains('my_module'))`

Comment: ok, and what do you want to do afterward? As I said, it really depends on what you want to do, so please provide a full example of what you want to achieve.